# Subgroup of the direct product of the rings or groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, direct-product

Hi I'm just consider the difference between groups and rings when it comes to direct product. And want to check this is right or not.

Let $A_i \le  B_i$ [The $A_i$ is a subobject(Subring or Subgroup) of the $B$]

It is obvious that

$A_i \le  B_i  \Rightarrow \Pi _{i=1} ^{n} A_i \le  B(=\Pi _{i=1} ^{n} B_i)$

Then question is

First)

Is it true that $A_i \le  B_i  \Leftarrow \Pi _{i=1} ^{n} A_i \le  B(=\Pi _{i=1} ^{n} B_i)$  ?

It looks like a not true but I couldn't find any counter examples.

Second )

$\forall$ suboject of ( $A_1 \times A_2\times...\times A_n$) = (subobject of $A_1$) $\times$ (subobject of $A_2$) $\times$ .... $\times$  (subobject of $A_n$)?

i.e. Can the all sub-objects(subrings or subgroups) of the $B$ be expressed  as a  $\Pi _{i=1} ^{n} A_i$ ?

Third)

If not, What conditions we need that the above things are true respectively with the case of the Ring and Group?

Comment: Suggestion: please remove the boldface type. It's bad for the same reason that writing in ALL CAPS is bad, it's like you are shouting at us.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Mosher. I just edited.

Comment: At the very least, you need to allow for a re-ordering of the $B_i$ before you include the $A_i$ into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is also no. Let $B_1=S_4$ and $B_2=S_3$. Let $A_1=C_6$, the cyclic group of order $6$, and let $A_2=C_2$, the cyclic group of order $2$. Then $A_1\times A_2$ embeds into $B_1\times B_2$ by taking the generators $\Bigl((1,2),(1,2,3)\Bigr)$ for the cyclic group of order $6$, and the generator $\Bigl((3,4),e\Bigr)$ for the cyclic group of order $2$. This generates a subgroup that is isomorphic to $A_1\times A_2$, so identify this product with that subgroup.

However, there is no way to embed $A_1$ into either $B_1$ or $B_2$, because neither $S_4$ nor $S_3$ have elements of order $6$.

Comment: Your subgroup $A_1$ is not isomorphic to $C_6$, rather $D_6$ (or $S_3$ if you like).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, Like the Mike said It looks like a $\Bigl((1,2),(1,2,3)\Bigr)$ generates the $S_3$ not $C_6$. Could you please more explain why does generates the $C_6$? So, does we need the other generator for $C_6$ not  $\Bigl((1,2),(1,2,3)\Bigr)$? Then Your counterexample definetly correct, I thought.

Comment: @Mike: You’re incorrect. Both $A_i$ are cyclic. Again: we have $S_4\times S_3$. The elements are ordered pairs, with the first entry in $S_4$ and the second entry in $S_3$. My **single** element is an ordered pair, $(\sigma,\tau)$, where $\sigma$ is the permutation $(1,2)$ in $S_4$, and $\tau$ is the permutation $(1,2,3)$ in $S_4$. It cannot be $S_3$ because it’s a **single element**. The subgroup consists of the elements $(e,e)$, $(\sigma,\tau)$, $(e,\tau^2)$, $(\sigma,e)$, $(e,\tau)$, and $(\sigma,\tau^2)$, which are the powers of $(\sigma,\tau)$.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang: No, Mike is wrong and so are you. It’s not $\langle (1,2),(1,2,3)\rangle$ (the subgroup generated by $(1,2)$ and $(1,2,3)$). It’s the cyclic subgroup generated by a single element of $S_4\times S_3$ of the form $(\sigma,\tau)$, $\sigma=(1,2)\in S_4$, $\tau=(1,2,3)\in S_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what you believe, I believe that the answer to your first question is YES. Here is why. If $\pi_k: \prod_{i=1}^nB_i \to B_k$ is the projection homomorphism of the $k^{th}$ component and $\prod_{i=1}^nA_i$ is a subgroup of the direct product, then $A_k = \pi_k(\prod_{i=1}^nA_i)$ is a subgroup of $B_k = \pi_k(\prod_{i=1}^nB_i)$ (since $\pi_k$ is a homomorphism). This also works for rings.

The answer to the second question is no. Consider the diagonal subgroup. Namely, if we consider the group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, then $\{(a,a):a\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, but is not in the form you described. This also works for rings.

As regards to your third question, I am not aware of any conditions (while I am sure there are some). For a very specific case, I think that you can prove that if you have a finite collection of groups whose orders are pairwise relatively prime, then any subgroup of the direct product will be a direct product of subgroups for each group separately. However, like I said this is a very specific case and does not completely answer the third question.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the inclusion is “nice” relative to the projections. Why can you do that? That is, you are assuming that the embedding of the product of the $A_i$ into that of the  $B_j$ will be such that the $j$th projection of the latter extends that of the former. I don’t think you can just assume that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I do not understand. The image of a subgroup is a subgroup. Isn't my method valid by that theorem?

Comment: Here’s how to clarify: you have *two* different products. Let $p_j$ be the projection onto the $A_j$ from $\prod A_i$; let $\pi_j$ be the projection onto $B_j$ from $\prod B_j$. You have an inclusion $\prod A_i\subseteq \prod B_j$, but this is just an embedding. You are *asuming* that $\pi_k|_{\prod A_i} = p_k$. But that is by no means a given. For a trivial example suppose $B_1=C_2$, $B_2=C_4$, $A_1=C_4$, $A_2=\{e\}$. The embedding does not satisfy the assumption you have. Worse, you could embedd the product of $A_1\times A_2$ as the subgroup generated by $(1,1)$. Your argument would not work

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin What is $C_2,C_4$?

Comment: Your argument would tell me in the latter case that $A_1=B_1$ and that $A_2=B_2$ (looking at the projections), which is false. (Or course, in the abelian case you can prove that one can find subgroups $D_j$ of each $B_j$ so that there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $A_i\cong D_{\sigma(i)}$, but I hope you see my point).

Comment: $C_n$= cyclic group of order $n$. You can’t assume that the embedding of $\prod A_i$ into $\prod B_i$ sends the abstract tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ into an identical tuple in the $B_i$, *especially* if  you don’t know that the $A_i$ are subgroups of the $B_i$ already.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But, doesn't $A_1 \subseteq B_2$? In your example, $C_4$ is not even a subset of $C_2$?

Comment: **That’s** the point! Even though $C_4\times \{1\}$ is a subobject of $ C_2\times C_4$, it is **not** the case that $C_4$ is a subobject of $C_2$ *and* $\{1\}$ is a subobject of $C_4$. Just because a subobject is, abstractly, a product, does not mean that the product structure is the **same** as that of the object.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, But if we add in the hypothesis that $A_i \subseteq B_i$ is my statement correct?

Comment: But if you add the hypothesis that $A_i\subseteq B_i$, then you are assuming what you are trying to prove, so what is the point?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't think so, you are just saying it is a subset, not necessarily a subgroup

Comment: You are **still** assuming what you are trying to prove. What you are trying to prove is that if $\prod A_i\subseteq \prod B_i$, then $A_j\leq B_j$ for each $j$. If you are assuming it is a subset but not a subgroup, then on what possible grounds could you conclude that $\pi_k(\prod A_i)$ is a subgroup of $B_k$? The image of a sub**set** need not be a subgroup.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin No, I am still assuming that $\prod A_i$ is a subgroup of $\prod B_i$

Comment: If $\prod A_i$ is a subgroup of $\prod B_i$, and the **subgroup** $A_i$ of $\prod A_i$ is a subset of the subgroup $B_i$ of $\prod B_i$, then you **are** assuming it is a subgroup.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What I am assuming is the following: $\prod A_i $ is a subgroup of $\prod B_i$ and $A_i$ is a subset of $B_i$. Then I claim that $A_i$ is in fact a subgroup of $B_i$. I am never assuming that $A_i$ is a subgroup. How is this assuming what you are trying to prove (I really do want to understand this.)

Comment: Because $A_i$ embeds into the product with the identity in all other coordinates as a subgroup of $\prod A_i$. Same with $B_i$. So assuming that $A_i$ is a subset of $B_i$ for each $i$ is exactly the same as assuming that $A_i$ is a subgroup of each $B_i$... which is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I do not know. I am having a difficult time seeing this. I still do not understand how the argument is circular. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: If $A_1$ is a subset of $B_1$, then the subgroup $A_1\times\{e\}\times\cdots\times\{e\}$ is a subset of the subgroup $B_1\times\{e\}\times\cdots\times\{e\}$. But that means that it is a subgroup, not merely a subset.

Comment: Doesn't the direct product being a subgroup automatically imply each component is a subset?

Comment: Of what? Of the whole thing, yes. But not of the corresponding factor.

Comment: is a subset of each component. How is this not so?

Comment: Then no. It does not. That’s the point. If it did, there would be nothing to prove.

Comment: I feel like there is because or else how would you know each component is atomically a subgroup.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Moreoever, I am never assuming that the "$A_i$ embeds into the product with the identity". My statement never indicates this.

Comment: That’s a basic property of the product of groups; you don’t need to assume it any more than you need to “assume” that the projections exist.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin But when you say that "Because $A_i$ embeds into the product with the identity in all other coordinates as a subgroup of $\prod A_i$" where is this coming from.

Comment: It comes from what the product of groups is! The map $a\mapsto (a,e,e,\ldots,e)$ is one-to-one group homomorphism from $A_1$ to $\prod A_i$; products of groups always have these embeddings. And for finitely many factors, so do rings (with unity).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I just do not understand. I will have to chat about this with somebody. Looking at your profile, you have been doing this much longer than me, so I am assuming you are correct (in which case I have to figure out what is wrong with my thinking). Thank you for bringing this to my attention.